# Passing parameters to a Selector in Swift using UITapGestureRecognizer, UIImageView and UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer

I need to identify the `image` that the user clicked on a `TableCell`.

How to pass `TAG`?

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var imgPost1: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    imgPost1.tag=1
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomCell.tappedMe))
    imgPost1.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    imgPost1.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
func tappedMe(xTag:Int) {
    print(xTag)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `view` property of the `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Register for tap gesture:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedMe:")
imgPost1.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
imgPost1.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Now define the tappedMe method

```
func tappedMe(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.view?.tag)
}
```

PS: Don't forget to set the tag for image

Comment: how do I set the tag for image ?

Comment: `yourImageView.tag = yourTag` For the above particular question set this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.